# How to use other URLs in CRUD API using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, crud, rest

I am trying to make a CRUD API using the Django Rest Framework.

Here is my urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('products', ProductView)

# router.register('products/delete/<id>', ProductView)
(This is not working)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Here is my views.py

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

By using the above code I can fetch a list of all products ---

1) localhost/products (This gives a list of all products)

2) localhost/products/1 (This gives a product with id 1)

How to use other URLs for operations such as Delete, Update etc.

*This above code is working. Nothing is wrong*. I Just want to know how to use other routes from the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this configuration, you will have two URLs

- `localhost/products/`
- `localhost/products/<product_pk>/`

But, the difference is ***which method is used to interact with the API***. I hope you already know we have got `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` etc HTTP methods and these above APIs are capable of those HTTP methods.

You can see the entire URL configuration (as table) [in DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter)

Comment: I know all of them. But yow to use there two urls with different methods like you mentioned delete put etc from client side.

Comment: I don't know which client you are using. But, I am sure that there will be something that let you send a request to ***`XYZ`*** URL with ***ABC*** HTTP method.